# Mongodb get specific properties in the aggregate result from a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm a little lost on how to use aggregate to obtain very specific type of results.
My db documents have the following format

```
{
  _id: 122434
  houseDetails: {
     hasBedroom: {
       flag: true,
     },
     hasKitchen: {
       flag: false
     },
     hasBalcony: {
       flag: false
     },
     hasFoyer: {
       flag: true
     },
  }
}
```

(This is a basic example of the structure of the document, the details are different)

I'm trying to query all the documents where the nested `houseDetails` properties are true.
So in the end I'd like the result to look like

```
{
  _id: 122434,
  houseDetails: [hasBedroom, hasFoyer]
}
```

I can use $match to find all the documents where at least one of the properties is true but I seem to be lost as to how to project only the names with the value true into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

1. Use `$objectToArray` to create an array from the keys and values
2. `$filter` it to keep only `true` values
3. `$match` to keep only documents with "valid" data.
4. Use `$map` to format the items

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {houseDetails: {$objectToArray: "$houseDetails"}}},
  {$project: {
      houseDetails: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$houseDetails",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.v.flag", true]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {"houseDetails.0": {"$exists": true}}},
  {$project: {
      houseDetails: {
        $map: {
          input: "$houseDetails",
          in: "$$this.k"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/djR6n8exVYi)

You can also use `$reduce` to do it in three steps only:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {houseDetails: {$objectToArray: "$houseDetails"}}},
  {$project: {
      houseDetails: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$houseDetails",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [{$eq: ["$$this.v.flag", true]}, ["$$this.k"], []]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$match: {"houseDetails.0": {"$exists": true}}},
```

See how it works on the [playground example - reduce](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6A37ZtBtn42)

Comment: It never occurred to me that I could use $project multiple times. Thanks, this is great!

Comment: I've noticed that I could use only the projects & maybe filter the final results by size of array (> 0). This will remove the $match stage. Is that ok to do? Or would that be more costly than fetching all the docs that has some houseDetails as true at the start before the projects?

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly you mean. Can you add a link to a playground example with your solution?

Comment: Well my current solution involves starting with a match like so - https://mongoplayground.net/p/3aQdTo0klei. But I was wondering if I should start with $projects like this - https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Y_eNTwzvOU & filter for non-empty houseDetails?

Comment: I would prefer to go like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/djR6n8exVYi), but it is not necessarily faster. If you have an index on all 4 fields and the majority of your documents has `false` on all 4, starting with a `$match` can be faster. Nevertheless It is not considered a good practice on mongoDB to maintain your index and query to each field separately and literally. This is not the best way to use the flexibility of mongoDB structure.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly